# Why does mysql source file can't run transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I source a foreign file by mysql command line:

```
source file.sql;
```

Or by this way:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -P 3306 database_name < file.sql
```

The file.sql is:

```
begin;
delete from table1;
insert into table1 values(1,'name');
-- commit;
```

When I run the schema in mysql command line,after I run rollback it can back to before.But the source method can not back to before.Why?

Comment: How is your [`autocommit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) set?

Comment: When I run `select @@autocommit;` it gave me 1.Even I add `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;` to the schema,the result was the same.